# Convert large decimal number to hexadecimal notation

Tags: string, swift3, integer, hex, decimal

When creating a String object in Swift you can use a [String Format Specifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW4) to convert an integer to hexadecimal notation.

```
print(String(format:"%x", 1234))
// output: 4d2
// expected output: 4d2
```

But when numbers become bigger, the output is not as expected.

```
print(String(format:"%x", 12345678901234))
// output: 73ce2ff2
// expected output: b3a73ce2ff2
```

It seems that the output of `String(format:"%x", n)` is truncated at 8 characters. I don't think in hexadecimal natively, this makes debugging hard. I have seen answers for other programming languages where it is explained that you need to brake-up the large integer into parts, but that seems wrong to me.

- What am I doing wrong here?
- What is the right way to convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal numbers in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%lx` or `%llx`

```
print(String(format:"%lx", 12345678901234))
```

> b3a73ce2ff2

Table 2 on the site you linked specifies them

> `l` - 
>   Length modifier specifying that a following d, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long or unsigned long argument.

`x` is for unsigned 32 bit integers which  only go up to 4.294.967.296